# How to convert a minute data to hourly data by average it

Tags: python

I am trying to convert my minute data to hour data and average the value.

My data sample is as below:

```
Date                   Property     value
2022-02-01 00:00:00     Power        4847
2022-02-01 00:00:00     Speed         47 
2022-02-01 00:00:00     Log           55
2022-02-01 00:01:00     Power        3325
2022-02-01 00:01:00     Speed         55
```

I've used below code to group them.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df1 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Date'), 'Property']).mean().reset_index
```

some how it returns only date and property column, Is there a way that I can get Value column as well?

My output is as below:
Doesn't know why value column is not come along with date and property

```
Date                   Property     
    2022-02-01 00:00:00     Power      
    2022-02-01 00:00:00     Speed      
    2022-02-01 00:00:00     Log          
    2022-02-01 00:01:00     Power    
    2022-02-01 00:01:00     Speed
```

Comment: You have typos: `pd.Groupder` -> `pd.Grouper` and `'Property'` -> `'property'`. Also _call_ `reset_index()` so that the returned value (and not the method itself) goes to `df1`. Then you get what you expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqUua.png

Comment: I still get same error even if I correct the typo

Comment: Can you show what you get? The exact code and dataframe you've given work fine for me.

Comment: I have edited the post. I only get Date and property column when I run the code but I want value column as well in my data.

Comment: Strange. What version of python and pandas are you using? Maybe someone else can replicate it...